Google Calendar no muestra las horas correctas de las reservas de Amelia
En mi pagina estoy usando el pluging Amelia para realizar reservas, la fecha y hora de la reserva deben mostrarse el Calendario de goodle de mis clientes y empleados. Todo estaba funcionando bien hasta hace casi mes que sin cambiar ninguna configuración, Google Calendar comenzó a desfazar los horarios de las reservas una hora antes a la indicada en Amelia. Ya revisé las configuraciones de zonas horarias de wordpress y google Calendario y se mantienen como siempre (ambos tienen Ciudad de Mexico).
Necesito saber como solucionar este problema, creo que es un problema de Google Calendar pero no se que hacer para solucionarlo.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Si no te registras, no podras hacer un uso correcto del sitio.. tambien, no sera un problema del plugin? sin ver el codigo, no podemos ayudarte con mucho...

Parece más una pregunta para el soporte del plugin de marras, no?
